# Round to 2 decimals in java

Tags: java, decimal

I have an array of numbers that have many decimal formats. How do I take that array and round everything to 2 decimal places? Ex 10.52

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/153753/2291134

Answer (score 0):

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); df.format(10.52777);

Answer (score 0):

trying using BigDecimal
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

When using you can then set the scale to 2 or whatever you want.  If however you just want to display as 2 digits then you can use `System.out.printf("%.2f", val);` or `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");`

Comment: I am not needing to print them out right now. I just need to take my array of numbers and cut them into 2 decimal places. The decimal format wouldnt work then.

Comment: so, as per the first part of my answer, use BigDecimal - perfect for rounding